# A question on the proof of Hartshorne's II Lemma 6.1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the proof of Lemma II.6.1 of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*,

> Let $U=$ Spec$A$ be an open affine subset of $X$ on which $f$ is regular. Then $Z = X-U$ is a proper closed subset of $X$. Since $X$ is Noetherian, $Z$ can contain at most finitely many prime divisors of $X$.

Why does $X$ being Noetherian imply that $Z$ can cantain at most finitely many prime divisors of $X$? By definition, $X$ can be covered by finitely many Spec $A_i$, where each $A_i$ is a Noetherian ring. So I think of the number of height $1$ prime ideals a Noetherian ring can contain. But this number can be infinite.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: A Noetherian ring has finitely many minimal primes over any $I$. But, note that since your thing is integral (I assume) a height $1$ prime is necessarily minimal over $(0)$.

Comment: I think one way to argue is that any prime divisor of $X$ contained in $Z$ is going to have to be an irreducible component of $Z$.

Comment: @Hoot Same thing :)

Comment: I agree, I agree.

Comment: @AlexYoucis First of all, there exists a noetherian ring which has infinitely many height 1 prime ideal: $\mathbb{Z}$. Also, since $X$ is assumed to be integral, $A$ itself is an integral domain. Hence, $(0)$ is a prime ideal, and, by definition, $(0)$ itself is the only minimal prime ideal over $(0)$. So, the argument in your first comment does not work in any direction.